# Generator in Python, representing infinite stream

Tags: python, loops, generator, index-error

My code is as follows:

```
def infinite_loop():
    li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    x = 0                           
   
    while True:
        yield li[x]
        if x > len(li):
           x = 0
        else:
           x += 1
```

I get a list index out of range error. What has gone wrong in my code?

Comment: You `yield` before checking if `x` is out of range. Try moving `yield li[x]` after assigning `x` value. Or you can use modulo operator yield `li[x % len(li)]`

Comment: Any particular reason you're coding this instead of using itertools.cycle, which does exactly that?

Comment: what are you trying to get? an infinite stream of a, b an c cycled?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Could you clarify what you mean by moving yield li [x], I am new to python and have trouble understanding such concepts

Comment: @SreeramTP Yes, I am trying to implement stream (infinite list)

Comment: @desperate_student I posted it as an aswer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @desperate_student - Take a look at my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test is off by 2.  The highest valid index is `len(li) - 1`, so after using that index, it needs to reset to `0`:

```
def infinite_loop():
    li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    x = 0                           
   
    while True:
        yield li[x]
        if x == len(li) - 1:
           x = 0
        else:
           x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access `li[x]` while `x` is equal or greater than the size of the list, it will throw `OutOfRange` exception.

```
    while True:
        # if x==3 this will throw error
        yield li[x]

        if x > len(li):
           x = 0
        else:
           x += 1
```

If you move `yield` after the `if` statement, the error will be gone

```
    while True:
        # if x==3, the following statement will assign 0 value to x
        # But you need to check with >= instead of >
        
        if x >= len(li):
           x = 0
        else:
           x += 1

        yield li[x]
```

But you can simplify it by using modulo operator (%)

```
    while True:
        yield li[x % len(li)]
        x += 1
```

Here's a working example: https://repl.it/@HarunYlmaz/python-generator